# Android NDK: custom pre-build step?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, makefile, custom-build-step

NDK 8b, Eclipse / Cygwin

I'm trying to add custom pre-build steps to Android.mk:

1) for every *.xyz file in the source tree, run a custom tool which generates corresponding .h and .cpp files

2) add the .cpp files to LOCAL_SRC_FILES

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372500/how-to-run-custom-rule-in-android-mk-before-compilation) and it's not quite what I'm looking for (it's only for one file)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651608/simplifying-an-android-mk-file-which-build-multiple-executables. I think you could adapt the answer to that question to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html you can use old-fashioned suffix rules:

```
source_xyz_files = a.xyz b.xyz
.xyz.cpp: $(source_xyz_files)
    if test "`dirname $@`" != "."; then mkdir -p "`dirname $@`"; fi
    tool_to_create_cpp_and_h_from_xyz $< $@ $(patsubst %.cpp,%.h,$@)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(patsubst %.xyz,%.cpp,$(source_xyz_files))
```

or patter rules:

```
generated_cpp_files = a.cpp b.cpp
$(generated_cpp_files) : %.cpp : %.xyz
    if test "`dirname $@`" != "."; then mkdir -p "`dirname $@`"; fi
    tool_to_create_cpp_and_h_from_xyz $< $@ $(patsubst %.cpp,%.h,$@)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(generated_cpp_files)
```